# Include a regex string in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I have an array made up of several strings that I am searching for in another array, like so:

```
strings_array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
main_array = [ ## this is populated with string values outside of my script ## ]

main_array.each { |item|
  if strings_array.any? { |x| main_array.include?(x) }
    main_array.delete(item)
  end
}
```

This is a simplified version of what my script is actually doing, but that's the gist. It works as is, but I'm wondering how I can make it so that the `strings_array` can include strings made out of regex. So let's say I have a string in the `main_array` called "string-4385", and I want to delete *any* string that is composed of `string-` + a series of integers (without manually adding in the numerical suffix). I tried this:

```
strings_array = ["string1", "string2", "string3", /string-\d+/.to_s]
```

This doesn't work, but that's the logic I'm aiming for. Basically, is there a way to include a string with regex like this within an array? Or is there perhaps a better way than this `.any?` and `include?` combo that does the job (without needing to type out the complete string value)?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You could treat every item in your `string_array` as a regex and instead of `main_array.include?(x)` you could check whether `main_array[x]`, `x` being a regex, returns `nil`, in which case there is no match.

Comment: You don't need "(ruby)" in the title since you have a Ruby tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is with `Regexp.union`, which combines multiple regular expressions into a single regex handy for matching.

```
patterns = [/pattern1/, /pattern2/, /string-\d+/]
regex = Regexp.union(patterns)
main_array.delete_if{|string| string.match(regex)}
```

Comment: "Regexp.union" is perfect! It incorporates into the rest of my script exactly as needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use methods like **keep_if** and **delete_if**, so if you want to delete strings that match a regex you could do something like this:

```
array = ['string-123', 'test']
array.delete_if{|n| n[/string-\d+/] }
```

That will delete the strings in the array that do not match your regex. Same thing with keep_if method.

Hope it helps!